# MS Graph - Get user time format access denied

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I've added the **MailboxSettings.Read** Application type scope to my app and I can read mailbox settings of users by id but I cannot read time zone and time format properties.
So, when I execute the following request: `GET v1.0/users/userId/mailboxSettings` I receive the following response:

```
{
    "@odata.context": "ctx",
    "archiveFolder": "...",
    "timeZone": "Vladivostok Standard Time",
    "delegateMeetingMessageDeliveryOptions": "sendToDelegateOnly",
    "dateFormat": "",
    "timeFormat": "",
    "automaticRepliesSetting": {
        "status": "disabled",
        "externalAudience": "all",
        "internalReplyMessage": "",
        "externalReplyMessage": "",
        "scheduledStartDateTime": {
            "dateTime": "2021-09-24T02:00:00.0000000",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        },
        "scheduledEndDateTime": {
            "dateTime": "2021-09-25T02:00:00.0000000",
            "timeZone": "UTC"
        }
    },
    "language": {
        "locale": "en-US",
        "displayName": "English (United States)"
    },
    "workingHours": {
        "daysOfWeek": [
            "monday",
            "tuesday",
            "wednesday",
            "thursday",
            "friday"
        ],
        "startTime": "08:00:00.0000000",
        "endTime": "17:00:00.0000000",
        "timeZone": {
            "name": "Vladivostok Standard Time"
        }
    }
}
```

Note that `dateFormat` and `timeFormat` are empty.
When I try to get only timeFormat I receive error message:

```
GET v1.0/users/userId/mailboxSettings/timeFormat
{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorAccessDenied",
        "message": "Access is denied. Check credentials and try again."
    }
}
```

Am I missing something? Looks like scope is configured correctly since I can get mailbox settings object but what should I do to get timeFormat and dateFormat?
Thanks for reading and your help!

**UPDATE:**
I've also tried to get Regional And Language Settings (which user can edit on [this page](https://myaccount.microsoft.com/settingsandprivacy/language)) from beta graph api: `GET beta/users/userId/settings/regionalAndLanguageSettings` but it returns empty result

```
{
    "@odata.context": "ctx",
    "defaultDisplayLanguage": null,
    "defaultRegionalFormat": null,
    "regionalFormatOverrides": null,
    "defaultSpeechInputLanguage": null,
    "defaultTranslationLanguage": null,
    "id": "id",
    "authoringLanguages": [],
    "translationPreferences": {
        "translationBehavior": "Ask",
        "untranslatedLanguages": [],
        "languageOverrides": []
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can reproduce the issue with empty `dateFormat` and `timeFormat` for my mailbox.

If you want to update mailbox settings or to get specific settings you need `MailboxSettings.ReadWrite` permission.

I've tried to update `dateFormat` and `timeFormat` by calling

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/mailboxSettings
{
    "@odata.context": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/$metadata#Me/mailboxSettings",
    "dateFormat": "yyyy-MM-dd",
}
```

But it returned

> FormatNotSupportedException. A valid Format value must be specified.
> The following Format value is not supported.

So, I've checked Outlook settings -> General settings and Language, Date format and Time format was set.
[image]
I've switched the language to another and back and saved changes.

Then Graph API returned not empty `dateFormat` and `timeFormat` for

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{user_id}/mailboxSettings
```

And also updating `dateFormat` and `timeFormat` is working but only if you specify one of the predefined format from the combo. Otherwise API will return `FormatNotSupportedException`

[image]

The fact that `dateFormat` and `timeFormat` is empty bye default looks like a bug in Outlook 365 API which is called under the hood by Graph API.

Comment: Thank you, but I don't need to update these settings. I need to read time format and date format for every user in a tenant and fact that this is empty is blocking me. Do you know where I could raise a bug for Outlook 365 API?